# Python Debugging: weird event when negative sign is in front

Tags: python

I was doing an assignment question.

Write a program, divisible_by_11(num), to return the divisibility of num
by 11. i.e. divisible_by_11(num) should return True is num is divisible by 11,
or False otherwise. Implement this function recursively and using the following algorithm.

Note: a number is divisible by 11 if the difference between the sum of odd digits
and the sum of even digits is divisible by 11. Note that 0 is divisible by 11.

```
def divisible_by_11(num):
    def helper(num,i):
        if num==0:
            return 0
        elif i%2:
            return helper(num//10,i+1)-num%10
```

> Question is about replacing the above line with `return -num%10+ helper(num//10,i+1)`

```
        elif i%2==0:
            return num%10+helper(num//10,i+1)

    return helper(num,0)%11==0
```

this code works, however if I wrote `return -num%10+ helper(num//10,i+1)` instead of `return helper(num//10,i+1)-num%10`, my code would fail. Can anyone tell me what's happening?

Comment: Not following the hypothetical case. Maybe put it in its own code block?

Comment: what do u mean hypothetical case? Does putting the -ve part right at the back of return command affect anything?

Comment: The "if I wrote..." part.

Comment: What do you mean "your code would fail"? What happens when you modify the code as you describe? (p.s. You know there is an easier way to test divisibility right? Hint: it involves the `%` operator.)

Comment: You cannot put `return` in the middle of a mathematical expression like that. `return` must be the first word in a statement.

Comment: If you're going to use the `%11` test at the end of the code, there's no reason to go through all the hoops with the recursive function first. Just do `return num % 11` and be done with it. If you're not allowed to do a mod 11 test (but can do mods of other numbers), you could use a while loop `while num > 10: num = helper(num, 0)` then return `num == 0` afterwards (outside the loop).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sry, I showed the wrong code that should be replaced, edited the post. Also, the question doesnt allow me to directly use % on the num itself

Comment: @Blckknght they wanted a recursive solution. My assignment came from a fundamentals course, so even if I know the easy way out, I'm not allowed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the alternate form is due to order of operations. The unary-minus operator binds more tightly than the mod operator. That is, the expression `-num%10` is interpreted as `(-num) % 10`, and the modulus of a negative number is not the same thing as its last digit.

There are a few ways you could fix it. The easiest would probably be to add your own parentheses so that the mod happens first: `return -(num%10) + helper(num//10,i+1)` should work as expected.

Unrelated to that issue, I'm very skeptical that your assignment allows you to do `%11` in the final return, since that operation is all you would need to solve the whole problem without the rest!

Instead, I suspect it wants you to use recursion for that part too (and maybe not for adding up the digits). Instead of `return helper(num,0)%11==0`, try:

```
while num > 10:
    num = helper(num, 0)

return num == 0
```